# Determining if a changed image is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a little gallery using jQuery and stuck on a small point

it's something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#thumb1').click(function(){
          $('#fullimage').attr('src','loading.gif').fadeOut(800,function(){
            $(this).attr('src','newimage.jpg').bind('onreadystatechange load', function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(300);       
            });

          });          
       });
//same code for $('#thumb2') etc.
});
</script>
<img src="defaultimage.jpg" id="fullimage" /><br />
<a><img id="thumb1" src="notimportantthumb.jpg"></a>
<a><img id="thumb2" src="notimportantthumb2.jpg"></a>
```

The thing is that, if the loading of the image takes more than 800ms, it won't work.

I know I have to use jQuery's load() or similar function, but I could not put it together. How can I identify if a changed image with jQuery is loaded or not ? 
Thanks

Edit: Solved with adding a second hidden image as a loader. If anyone's interested:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumb1').click(function(){
        if ($('#fullimage').attr('src')!='newimage.jpg') { //it would not load, just show the loading.gif

            $('#fullimage').hide(); $('#hiddenloader').show();
              $('#fullimage').attr('src','newimage.jpg').load(function(){
                $('#hiddenloader').fadeOut(300,function(){
                    $('#fullimage').fadeIn(300);
                });

                });

          }
    });
//same code for $('#thumb2') etc.
});
</script>
<img src="defaultimage.jpg" id="fullimage" /><br />
<img src="loading.gif" id="hiddenloader" style="display: none;" />
<a><img id="thumb1" src="notimportantthumb.jpg" /></a>
<a><img id="thumb2" src="notimportantthumb2.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: Why are you giving it `loading.gif` then fading it out? And you're not assigning the `newimage.jpg` to the src until after the fadeOut, so what does the 800ms has to do with it?

Comment: If a thumbnailchanger images are clicked, I want to change the source to loading.gif immediately, then if the image that would be change is loaded, I want to fadeout, change the source , then fadein. 800 ms is made up by me (like an average image loading time) just post here and explain where I'm stuck at.

Comment: Yes, but the way it is right now, you're giving it `loading.gif`, then you're fading it out immediately, then when the fade is done, you're assigning the `newimage.jpg`. So the new image won't begin loading until after the loading image has faded away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the onload event should fire any time the src attribute changes and the image finishes loading

Edit for code sample:

```
$('#thumb1').click(function(){
    $('#fullimage').attr('src','loading.gif').fadeOut(800,function(){
            $(this).attr('src','newimage.jpg').load(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(300);       
        });
    });          
});
```

Though I will say that this method of presenting a loader image is slightly unusual.

Comment: Edited answer to include sample code.  You were already pretty close, as you can see.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I can't see a difference between your code and mine, only except I binded onreadystatechange and load. What I need is not to fadeout for 800ms and then change img src, but to change after image is loaded.

Comment: Marking as accepted, because your note encouraged me a trick, which works flawlessly (added to top), thanks!

Comment: Heh, I am a mootools guy.  I had that solution in mind, and tried to write it in jQuery... bleargh!  I didn't want to give you a mootools or vanilla solution since you're in jQuery.  Glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 0):

Can you preload the images on load.

http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript

Comment: Well I also thought that, but preloading sadly is not an option.